# Elasticsearch query by using scroll id returns index not found exception

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

While querying on indices it is giving results as expected but while giving scroll id returns the status as 404. and the error is `type: "index_not_found_exception"`

the scroll id length is 5604.

Comment: You should probably show the commands you're running.

Comment: The command I used is `http://hostname:portnumber/_search/scroll?scroll_id=scroll_id`

Comment: A scroll request is done in [two steps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html), are you doing them correctly?

Comment: Yes,  The scrolling is working fine. If I am selecting some 10 indices. If the scroll_id length below 4000. It is working fine. if the length is crossed to 4000 it is raised above exception. Is there any mx_length for scroll_id or max number indices to select at a time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try doing POST request instead of GET?

You don't have to pass it as part of the URL. You can simply send it in the 
request body 
(http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/). 
ref: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ridiculously-long-scroll-id/12913/4

Comment: Agreed!
Updated now.